# Laravel Home page return 404 after setup in my local from server

Tags: laravel-4

I setup laravel server code to in my localhost, update data details. But I'm facing issue for `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` I'm run with localhost/sitename/public but return 404.

Comment: What do you get when you just look for http://localhost?

Comment: yes, in localhost.

Comment: When you go to `http://localhost/sitename/public` you get a 404. Do you get 404 when you go to `http://localhost/`?

Comment: input in terminal php -S localhost:8001 -t public than run http://localhost:8001 - I'm also trying with, but return in terminal message like 404